# deleting header lines with no following content lines using awk

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

I think I've done this a couple of times but I can't do it this morning.
I have a file like this for example. (this is the result of comparison of many files using foreach and diff, with file names enclosed with ### pattern)

```
<< file gg >>

### ./translations/qt_fr.ts ###
### ./translations/qt_es.ts ###
### ./translations/qt_help_hu.ts ###
### ./transla file 1 _help_hu.ts ###
< alala0
------
> blabla0
### ./translations/qt_help_hu.ts ###
### ./translations/qt_help_hu.ts ###
### ./translations/qt_help_hu.ts ###
### ./translations/qt_help_hu.ts ###
### ./translations/qt_help_hu.ts ###
### ./transl file 2 t_help_hu.ts ###
< alala0
< alala1
--------
> blabla0
> blabla1
### ./translations/qt_help_hu.ts ###
### ./translations/qt_help_hu.ts ###
### ./translations/qt_help_hu.ts ###
### ./translations/qt_help_hu.ts ###
### ./translations/qt_help_hu.ts ###
```

what I want to do is remove those lines with only file name to produce output like below.

```
(expected output)

### ./transla file 1 _help_hu.ts ###
< alala0
------
> blabla0
### ./transl file 2 t_help_hu.ts ###
< alala0
< alala1
--------
> blabla0
> blabla1
```

How can I do this wit awk? I tried this(I tried to make it look like C, the same). I call the line with ### 'header' line. The logic is : I print all the non-header line, but if the previous line was a header, print the previous line. For this, I keep any header line in the 'kept' variable.

```
<< file tt.awk >>

{if ($0 !~ /^###/)
        if (flag == 1) {print $kept; print $0;}
        else {print $0}
}

{if  ($0 ~ /^###/)
        flag = 1;
else
        flag = 0;
kept = $0;
}
```

When I run `awk -f tt.awk gg`, I get this result. The 'kept' is not from the previous line but the current line. What's wrong with the awk code? A long-time awk user, I maybe missing something important.

```
< alala0
< alala0
------
> blabla0
< alala0
< alala0
< alala1
--------
> blabla0
> blabla1
```

Comment: The problem is `$kept`. You don't use `$` on normal awk variables. `$1`, etc. are the actual names. So you want `print kept`. That being said the other changes in John1024's answer are also good. Use the built-in pattern matching actions rather than `if`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the existing code work, replace:

```
    if (flag == 1) {print $kept; print $0;}
```

With:

```
    if (flag == 1) {print kept; print $0;}
```

#### Other approaches

```
$ awk '/^###/{kept=$0;f=1;next} f {print kept} {f=0;print}' gg
### ./transla file 1 _help_hu.ts ###
< alala0
------
> blabla0
### ./transl file 2 t_help_hu.ts ###
< alala0
< alala1
--------
> blabla0
> blabla1
```

For simplicity, the flag `f` can be eliminated:

```
$ awk '/^###/{kept=$0;next} kept {print kept} {kept="";print}' gg
### ./transla file 1 _help_hu.ts ###
< alala0
------
> blabla0
### ./transl file 2 t_help_hu.ts ###
< alala0
< alala1
--------
> blabla0
> blabla1
```

Comment: I see. your suggestion looks nicer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is simpler:

```
{
    if ($0 ~ /^###/)
    { kept = $0; flag=1; }
    else if (flag == 1) {print kept; print $0; flag=0}
    else {print $0}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using a sed approach

```
sed '/^###.*###/d' file
```

find all lines with patter and delete
or

```
sed -n '/^###.*###/!p' file
```

find all lines without pattern ### and print